# Messed up with Java Declaration

Tags: java, unicode, character, declaration

why java constant have strange behaviour (Unicode Character and normal representation)..     I mean see below example.
Note : All code is in java language.

```
char a = '\u0061';   //This is correct
char 'a' = 'a';     //This gives compile time error
char \u0061 = 'a';  //this is correct no error
ch\u0061r a = 'a';  //This too works
ch'a'r a = 'a';     // This really is confusing compile time error
```

Why last declaration is not works whereas `ch\u0061r a='a';` works?

Comment: @Subhrajyoti Majumder Thanks for Editing..

Answer (score 2):

You cannot put literals (`'a'`) in the middle of identifiers.

The line

```
char 'a' = 'a';
```

Does not compile because there is no identifier, and you cannot assign one literal to another.

Unicode is permitted, however. It is just hard to read :-)

Comment: Identifiers and literals are two different things in almost all commonly used languages. In Java they cannot be mixed. It's the rules of Java :-)

Comment: @Level29Access `Unicode composite characters are different from the decomposed characters`

Answer (score 1):

You can not put literal characters, `'a'`, in identifiers. You can use unicode, `\u0061`, though.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't confusing at all. You're randomly scattering single quotes around and expecting them to be irrelevant. In the first case, you're assigning the value of the single character `\u0061` to a `char` variable. Then you're trying to use a character literal as a variable name, which doesn't work. Then you're using a Unicode-formatted character (not quoted) as a variable name, which is okay. Perhaps you're confusing Java's quote rules with shell?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the reason in [specification of literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/lexical.html#3.8)

> Unicode composite characters are different from the decomposed characters.

```
Identifier:
        IdentifierChars but not a Keyword or BooleanLiteral or NullLiteral

IdentifierChars:
        JavaLetter
        IdentifierChars JavaLetterOrDigit

JavaLetter:
        any Unicode character that is a Java letter (see below)

JavaLetterOrDigit:
        any Unicode character that is a Java letter-or-digit (see below)
```